# What's better: date() or DateTime::format()?

Tags: php, date

I'm working in a server environment with PHP 5.3.

To create a MySQL `DATETIME` string representing the current time, I just have used `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` in my code. Something like `new DateTime("now")->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")` simply can't be parsed in this version. However, I'm figuring if I can rely in `date()` function to do this.

And in some source files I'm using `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $mysqlDate)->format('d/m/Y H:i')` to obtain a more friendly date for brazilian visitors.

**The question**: is this spaghetti code? What can I do for have a more concise code?

Comment: Use whatever is easier for you to write and maintain

Comment: You need to watch out with `d/m/Y`. If you work with it (like strtotime), PHP will interpret it as `m/d/Y` (American) and so it can cause errors

Comment: DateTime objects - handle timezones and daylight savings, handle a much wider range of dates, ease of integration with DateIntervals and DatePeriods - get in the habit of using them, and they make a whole lot of things easier

Comment: Why not use MySQL to [format dates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)?

Comment: @JohnConde This is my first assumption.

Comment: @hd1 I'm using a very simple ORM. And I'm a little bit confused with database formating; I don't know if it's a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datetime is a little more fast [SEE HERE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/c9sQs2) and have the daylight timezone support, however also date() can be good for a fast code, because it's better use Datetime with a oop logic

```
$st = microtime();
echo date('m/d/Y H:i').' '.(microtime()-$st).'<br>';
$st = microtime();
$d = new Datetime();
echo $d->format('d/m/Y H:i').' '.(microtime()-$st);
```

You can also use datetime in procedural style

```
echo date_format(date_create($date),$format);
```

Comment: Hi Sam, to make your answer shine, consider bringing in some of the context from the link into the body of your answer. If the link were to break, your answer would still be useful to future visitors with the same problem. Good luck!

Comment: My problem it's that `$d` variable. Should I always create a temporary variable to call `format()` method?

Comment: @tassoevan you can use procedural style, like date_format(date_create($date),$format)

Comment: Oh, pretty good, @Sam. Please, edit and put this in your answer.

Comment: Motivation of the -1?